# How to switch from PIO to DMA modes on a SATA Controller in code?

Tags: c, windows, device-driver, sata

I am running windows 7.  I need build an unattended/automated test to exercise some SATA drives.  One of the test requirements is to exercise the drive with DMA in both states (enabled AND disabled).

To manually change this setting, you would:

```
   1) Open Device Manager.
   2) Expand "IDE ATA/ATAPI controllers".
   3) Pick one of the ATA Channels listed; right-click properties; Advanced tab.
   4) Toggle "Enable DMA".
```

As I said, I need to do this unattended.  Any ideas on how it could be done?  I have searched Windows Dev Center high and low, including the Device instance and setup stuff in the driver development kit.  I can't find anything relevant there.  I've also searched for registry keys that might do the job, but haven't found anything there either.